# In PowerBI how to set Server Side Properties for ODBC connections?

Tags: hive, powerbi, odbc, powerbi-desktop

When making a simple SQL query in Hive using the ODBC driver it by default prepends the table name to the column name. This is the behavior even if I select just one table.

I can turn off this behavior with the command `set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false`

I successfully set it using DBeaver SQL Client connected with the ODBC Driver. In languages like R there is a special [special syntax to set server side properties](https://community.rstudio.com/t/send-hiveconfs-with-odbc-hive-query/63433/4?u=hadley) while creating the connection.

I managed to set the parameter directly in my Windows ODBC connection int "Advanced Options" → "Server Side Properties", **but I would like to set it while creating the connection**:
[image: configuring column names]

Using PowerBI, I couldn't find a way to set `hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names`. I tried to execute it before my query, but it didn't work.

How would I set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names to false while using PowerBI?

Answer (score 0):

You can set properties either in your ODBC connection string

[image]

or in a DSN.

[image]

But properties not settable in the ODBC connection string or in the DSN UI cannot be set from Power BI.

Comment: Please show me the syntax to set the `hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false` in the connection string. It didn't work. As I told in the OG, I don't want to do it in the DSN setup.

Comment: See your ODBC driver docs for supported connection string parameters.